# Creating thumbnail of image and uploading in s3 bucket

Tags: node.js, file-upload, amazon-s3

I am getting an image in file parameter. I need to convert it to thumbnail and then upload both images to s3 bucket. Please suggest a way out. I just don't know how to start with.

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to do the same thing. For now, take a look at https://github.com/bcoe/thumbd